# how to get variable outside router.get() in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mern

```
global.folder_name= null ;

// upload = uploadFunc.echo('ild')
// At Route /upload/ild
router.post('/',(req, res)=>{
    folder_name = req.body.folder_name;
    console.log(`inside route ${folder_name}`)
    res.status(200).redirect('/upload/ild/done')
    
})

upload = uploadFunc.echo(folder_name);
console.log(folder_name)


// At Route /upload/ild/
router.get('/done', upload.array('avatar'), (req, res) => {


    return res.json({ status: 'OK' });
});
```

above code is giving undefined in the console inside the '/' route
I want to get the folder the folder name from one route and pass it to the other route...

Answer (score 0):

1st solution(global variable):

```js
let folder_name = null;

router.post('/',(req, res)=> {
  folder_name = req.body.folder_name;
});

upload = uploadFunc.echo(folder_name);
```

2nd solution(use upload block inside router):

```js
router.post('/',(req, res)=> {
  folder_name = req.body.folder_name;
  upload = uploadFunc.echo(folder_name);
});
```